# How to pass a type to a method, by finding the type by its name in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a method which checks the current game state and returns boolean if the passed value is equal to the current one:

```
        public bool IsEqualToCurrentState<T>() where T : GameState
        {
            if (currentGameState is T)
                return true;

            return false;
        }
```

I have multiple gamestates, a few of them being: `PointTutorialState, GrabTutorialState, MoveTruckState`...

Normally I would call the method this way:

```
GameStateManager.Instance.IsEqualToCurrentState<PointTutorialState>()
```

Now, I am writing a script which would be used on multiple `gameObjects` and should highlight the object if the state is the one that the `gameObject` is responsible for. So, the only difference is the type of the state for that object.

My ideas was to make a serializeField string, where the name of the type for that object would be stored and call the method `IsEqualToCurrentState<>()`

I tried searching in google but I had no luck in finding what I needed. ChatGPT also couldn't help me, but this is what it wrote:

```
    private bool MatchesTheGameState()
    {
        Type newType = Type.GetType(nameState);
        MethodInfo method = typeof(GameStateManager).GetMethod("IsEqualToCurrentState");
        MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(newType);
        return (bool)genericMethod.Invoke(GameStateManager.Instance, null);
    }
```

accepting that nameState is this line of code:

```
    [SerializeField] string nameState;
```

with value: PointTutorialState

Any solutions how I can call the IsEqualToCurrentState method by just giving the name of the desired state and converting it to that type so I can pass it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply compare the type name, this is basically enough.

```
public bool IsEqualToCurrentState(string stateName)
    => currentGameState?.GetType().Name == stateName;
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bunch of if statements in your Update() methods that could get complicated and buggy.

Events would make this easier and cleaner, a working example at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4JlFxPcqlg

You call OnPointTutorialState in the place where you would set the state to PointTutorialState, and then in any object that needs to change for that state change, add an event handler that makes the changes you need for that event. Depending on the object and your state needs, you might also need an OnPointTutorialStateExit event.

Finally, this could clean things up a bit in that when you are done with tutorials, you could disable all the tutorial state/event listeners.

Comment: I should add there are MANY event system designs out there. If you don't like the scripts referencing each other above, there's this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gx0Lt4tCDE0 (uses singletons) and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8WHdMI8hxk (uses ScriptableObjects) -- and many others if you search.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description, it was really helpful!